# NameValuePair variables not received by php

Tags: php, android, post

I am trying to send some data from my android project to a php script for storing in external database. This is how my method to send the data looks like:

```
public void execute(String inComment, LatLng inLatLng)
{
    double lat = inLatLng.latitude;
    double lng = inLatLng.longitude;
    
    Log.d("general", Double.toString(lat));
    Log.d("general", Double.toString(lng));
    Log.d("general", inComment);
    
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", inComment));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", Double.toString(lat)));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", Double.toString(lng)));
    
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_create_product);
        
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        
        Log.d("general", "" + response.getStatusLine());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("error", "Error:  " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

The result of the logging is:

> 13.0
>
> 12.0
>
> test comment
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK

My php script just looks like this:

```
<?php

// location data
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lng = $_POST['lng'];
    
// comment data
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

?>
```

And the error I get is:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: lat
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: lng
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: comment
```

As if the data was not posted to the php script. What could be wrong here?

Comment: How are you checking the values of the PHP variables?

Comment: in the real code I use if(isset($_POST['lat']) && ... ){} to check all POST but for testing I now use if(true){}. Then I have a mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO location(`Lat`, `Lng`) VALUES('$lat', '$lng')");

Comment: ok I solved this, the problem was that the URL to the script was using a domain name pointing to the IP the php script is located on, instead of using IP:PORT. It may have to do with which port is being used??